# How to count the number of intersections of distinct events $(A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k}A_j), i_{1}<\cdots<i_{k}, j\notin \{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

I am learning Probabilities with the Textbook **"Introduction to Probability Models 10th Ed."** by Sheldon Ross.
At page 74, there is the section covering the distribution of the number of events that occur.

Consider arbitrary events $ A_1,\dots,A_n$. For $1\leq k\leq n$, let
$$S_k=\sum_{i_1<\dots< i_k}P(A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k})$$
Clearly, this equals the sum of the probabilities of all $\binom{n}{k}$ intersections of $k$ distinct events.

Now consider
$$\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_k}\sum_{j\notin \{i1,\dots,i_k\}}P(A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k}A_j)$$

> The probability of every intersection of $k+1$ distinct events $A_{m_1}\cdots A_{m_{k+1}}$ will appear $\binom{k+1}{k}$ times in this multiple summation. This is so because each choice of $k$ of its indices to play the role of $i_1,\dots,i_k$ and the other to play the role of $j$ results in the addition of the term $P(A_{m_1}\cdots A_{m_{k+1}})$. Hence,
>   \begin{align}\sum_{i_1<\dots< i_k}\sum_{j\notin \{i1,\dots,i_k\}}P(A_{i_1}\cdots A_{i_k}A_j)&=\binom{k+1}{k}\sum_{m_1<\dots< m_{k+1}}P(A_{m_1}\cdots A_{m_{k+1}})\\
> &=\binom{k+1}{k}S_{k+1}\end{align}

I cannot understand the last idea. Why is it that in the multiple summation, the probability of every intersection of $k+1$ distinct events $A_{m_1}\cdots A_{m_{k+1}}$ will appear $\binom{k+1}{k}$ times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if $(m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4) = (1,3,4,6)$, then $P(A_1 A_3 A_4 A_6)$ appears $4$ times in the double summation corresponding to the following choices of $(i_1, i_2, i_3), j$:

- $(1,3,4), 6$
- $(1,3,6), 4$
- $(1,4,6), 3$
- $(3,4,6), 1$